# keeping indefinite article in front of each quality in first description of someone

Tags: indefinite-article

When I first describe a certain person by providing three qualities (passive, quiet, friendly), two of which are rather negative (passive, quiet) and the last (friendly) is positive, can I keep the indefinite article in front of each quality or is it sounding funny?:

> Kate is a bit passive and a bit quiet, although a rather friendly
>   student.

Comment: Your sentence is fine.  Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: @Peter - I thought my usage of the article "a" was redundant in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can say "a bit passive and a bit quiet" or "a bit passive and quiet". If you include "bit", then you need to include the indefinite article as well.

Both are correct. The choice is up to you.

Comment: Thank you. Can I also drop "a" before "rather friendly student"?

Comment: @brilliant: NO, you cannot drop "a" before "rather friendly student"